# SAS proc SQL: Extract number in front of the word 'Month' or 'Months'

Tags: sql, sas, numbers, extract

I want to extract a number from a string where it is directly followed by the word 'Month' or 'Months'.

The search should be case insensitive and the text to look in typically looks like

```
No interest 18 months, no promo payments due = 18 
No interest  24 months, no promo payments due = 24 
No interest  12 months, no promo payments due = 12
```

In `db2` I use this with:

```
xmlcast(xmlquery('let $r := fn:replace($s, ".* (\d+) *month.*", "$1", "i") return if ($r castable as xs:integer) then xs:integer($r) else ()' passing ' '|| TABLE.PLAN_DESC  as "s") as int)
```

How can I convert this to SAS `proc sql`?

Comment: Do you need only the first occurence of a number preceding "month" or "months", or all such numbers?

Comment: Please be specific: should the search be case sensitive, for instance? Will the number be surrounded by blanks, by non numeric characters or by any special characters? Please supply some example strings.

Comment: Please supply the SAS code to which you want to add this. It makes a hell of a difference if it is `SQL` or a SAS `data` step

Comment: i only need the number directly preceding the word month or months. The search should not be case sensitive. The examples are shown above;  No interest 18 months, no promo payments due = 18 No interest 24 months, no promo payments due = 24 No interest 12 months, no promo payments due = 12

Lastly, it would be located in proc sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## A simple solution

```
input(scan(substr(myText, 1, find(myText, 'month', 'i') -1), -1), 8.)
```

In this

- `find` with the `i` modifier looks case insensitive for the string `month` in `myText`
- `substr` returns the part in front of it
- `scan` with `-1` as position returns the last word before month
- `input` applies the format `8.` to read that word as a number of up to 8 digits

#### Disclaimer

- This code is not tested
- It will only find one occurance of `month` in a string
- It will also find a number in front of `monthly`, for instance

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution attacking the problem in a less than elegant, but quite intuitive way:

Search for the first occurrence of "month" (will also find "months" (well, "month*")). Record the position where it starts. 
Loop backwards from that position, collecting digits of the number.
When encountering a character that's not a digit nor a blank, stop. Store the number. 
Repeat with the remaing part of the string, until there are no more occurrences of "month".

```
data test_data;
    infile datalines truncover;
    input testcase $200.;
datalines; 
No interest 18 months, no promo payments due = 18 No interest 24 months, no promo payments due = 24 No interest 12 months, no promo payments due = 12
jfjfjfjf1monthfjfjfj2months
jfjfjfjf1 monthfjfjfj 2 months
;

data extract_numbers;
    set test_data;
    length number numbers $ 1000.;
    string=testcase;
    do while (find(string, 'month', 'i')>0);
        monthpos=find(string, 'month', 'i');
        number="";
        do i=monthpos-1 to 0 by -1;
            character=substr(string,i,1);
            if anydigit(character)=1 then number=cat(strip(character), strip(number));
            else if character ne " " then do;
                if numbers="" then numbers=strip(number);
                else numbers=cat(strip(numbers),"-", strip(number));
                string=substr(string,monthpos+5);
                leave;
            end;
        end;
    end;
    keep testcase numbers;
run;
```